# What is a good way to provide common methods to all of my services in Grails?

Tags: grails

Do you suggest that I use Inheritance, Mixins, ExpandoMetaClass or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your common methods are largely related to one another, use inheritance from a common class containing them.

If however you have separate concerns and would benefit from grouping them into more than one file, I suggest [traits](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/core-traits.html) - they have deprecated Groovy's `@Mixin` annotation.

I'm using them to decorate my controllers and they have worked out very nicely. I have read somewhere that the Grails team is also going to use them to replace the 'magic' metaclass decoration of artefacts like controllers (which is how methods like `render` are currently provided).. can't find the link, though :(

Comment: Right. The Grails 3 infrastructure makes heavy use of traits. Very good answer here.

Comment: its mentioned here http://www.slideshare.net/graemerocher/springone-2gx-2014-grails-30-preview e.g. http://image.slidesharecdn.com/2gx2014-grails3-140912111451-phpapp01/95/grails-30-preview-43-638.jpg?cb=1410538570

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this behavior to services in your application and also those from plugins, use the `getServiceClasses()` dynamic method in `GrailsApplication` and add to their metaclasses, e.g.

```
def grailsApplication
....
grailsApplication.serviceClasses.each { sc ->
   sc.clazz.metaClass.foo = { bar -> ... }
}
```